# Does heating an electromagnet cause change in its magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics

Does heating an electromagnet cause change in its magnetic field as well and vice versa?

Comment: If the heating changes the current flowing, sure, otherwise, no. Is there something less obvious you think is at play here?

Comment: not really. Was just curious. @ACuriousMind

Comment: Heating of the pole pieces (if present) could also impact the field at the point of interest. We do use water cooling on our larger magnets on our ion accelerators to stabilize the magnetic field, but that is on the coils, not the pole pieces to avoid the heating-induced resistivity changes pointed out by @ACuriousMind.

Comment: If you're curious about magnets and temperature, check out "Curie temperature" which applies to magnets (non-electro)

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume your electromagnet is an inductor powered by a battery with constant potential $V$. The magnetic field is proportional to the intensity running on the wires. $B\propto I$. We know: $V = RI$, where $R$ is the resistance of the inductor. Its a very simple model as you can see...

For a small variation of temperature from initial temperature $T_0$, the resistance can be approximated with a linear relation:
$$
R = R(T_0)\left[1 + \alpha\left(T - T_0\right)\right]
$$

You can google to find $\alpha$ for a given material arround $T_0$ that you want to work with. So, in the vicinity of $T_0$, and with the temperature coeficient $\alpha$ measured/given, we can now conclude:

- If $\alpha > 0$, resistance increases, current decreases, magnetic field decreases.
- If $\alpha < 0$, resistance decreases, current increases, magnetic field increases.
- If $\alpha = 0$, nothing happens.

There is a [table on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity#Resistivity_and_conductivity_of_various_materials) which contains resistivity of several materials and their temperature coeficient arround $T_0 = 293K$.

Comment: Some values for alpha: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-12/temperature-coefficient-resistance/